# Emailhashes are not available in Users.xml

Tags: support, profile-picture, gravatar

I'm making a list of users identicons, and given that I should get the `Users.xml` file from an archive to find email hashes in order to make the user identicons in Gravatar.

Obviously in the title, these emails doesn't seem to be available in the file mainly due to privacy reasons.

Now I want to actually get the identicons in a different way. How do I do so?

Comment: Umm, for close voters, this question is possibly about Stack Exchange data dumps and Stack Overflow users' identicons, so it is kind of related to Stack Overflow, unless it's preferred to migrate it to Meta Stack Exchange instead...

Comment: @AndrewT. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: *"That's what I'm talking about"* ... Then should be explicitly stated in question. Otherwise this could be a generic question about any site's users.xml and unanswerable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Anything* that can be used to identify a user is stripped from the data dump.
Obviously, this includes hashed emails, as they're basically unique Ids you can use.

If what you want is to generate the user's *actual* identicon from the data dump, there is simply no way.